# How do I make android:textIsSelectable="true" work with my intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm having trouble making my `textview` editable - while I can make it editable, I can't pass the text to another activity via an `intent`.

In the `xml` of my `View` activity, for my `textViewComment` textbox, I have:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewComment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/textboxes_for_contact"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

The text in the `textbox` is indeed selectable, I am able to copy it with a long press.

However, I have an `Edit` activity - when an edit button is clicked in `View` activity, the text in `textViewComment` should be passed to this `Edit` activity with an `intent`. Instead, the `Edittext` in my `EditView` is empty.

When I remove `android:textIsSelectable="true"` the text is passed via the intent successfully. But... I can't edit it in the `textview`.

I also tried it programmatically with `commentname.setTextIsSelectable(true);` but this gives the same problem.

In `ViewContact` class I have

```
i.putExtra("comment", commentname.getText());
```

In `EditContact` class:

```
comment = i.getStringExtra("comment");
```

The `xml` in my `EditContact` class for `textViewComment` is:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textViewComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:background="@drawable/textboxes_for_contact"
            android:maxLength="360"
            />
```

Any idea how I can make the text in `ViewContact` selectable while also passing the `intent` successfully? Is this a known issue?

Comment: i.putExtra("comment", commentname.getText().toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
 i.putExtra("comment", commentname.getText());
```

with:

```
 i.putExtra("comment", commentname.getText().toString());
```

and see if you have better luck.